# Git: How do I undo a cherry-pick --no-commit that generated conflicts?

Tags: git, git-bash

I executed a git cherry-pick XXX --no-commit. I believe this just updates the staging area and the working directory and does not commit anything. The problem is that after executing this command I got many conflicts. How do I undo this? I want to go back to the way it was before the command. I ran this on a patch branch. what command do I execute?

Comment: Try `git cherry-pick --abort`.

Comment: Was there anything not commit before cherry-pick command.

Comment: I had committed previous cherry-picks yes. But the last one I did was with the --no-commit option, and it generated conflicts. So I want to undo this last cherry-pick.

Comment: @ElpieKay I tried git cherry-pick --abort but I got a message "no cherry-pick or revert in progress"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git reset --hard HEAD` will restore the state of last commit. (Then you'll be able to resume your cherry-picking process, or not, or in a different order.)